# Vue как отличать разные типы компонентов

Tags: архитектура, vue.js, чистый-код

У меня есть несколько типов компонентов.

1. Компоненты части страницы, например панелька, список лайков.
   Эти компоненты просто часть разметки других страниц, сами они никакие fetch запросы не делают, просто отображают некоторые данные.
2. Компоненты которые делают fetch запрос, например разделы форума, в зависимости от имени форума подгружают с сервера данные и выводят их.
3. Компоненты страницы, то есть это полноценная страница, которая выводится в системе роутинга и своём layout.

По сути это разные типы компонентов, и я думаю что хорошо бы как-то их отличать на уровне названий.

Думаю что компоненты части страниц (1) просто названиями называть, например `Likes`.

Компоненты с fetch (2) добавлять в название `WithGetData` или `WithFetch`, например `ForumThreadPanelWithGetData`

Компоненты странички (3) называть c `Page` префиксом, например `ForumPage`.

Если (2) и (3) вместе, то просто с `Page` префиксом делать без `WithGetData`

Как считаете на сколько это разумно и хорошо, у кого какой опыт в подобных вопросах.

Answer (score 4):

Для данных нужен `vuex`. Если нужно запрашивать данные при переходах, то делать это в хуках роутов. Компоненты - это реактивный DOM. Vuex + API утилиты - это данные. **И тогда не будет смысла в таких названиях**. В приложении будет один источник данных, один источник "истины".

Для сложных приложений (типа форума или магазина) это просто необходимо.

Хранилище Vuex "реактивно" и компоненты просто реагируют на изменения в нём. А также могут инициировать изменения (commit, mutations).

- https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/
- https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html
- примеры приложений - https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples

дополнение к комментариям:

Хранилище `Vuex` это состояние приложения. Данные могут сохраняться где угодно, например кэшироваться в LocalStorage. **Смысл в том, что на изменения данных могут реагировать разные компоненты одновременно** и layout, и page, и navbar, уведомления и т.д. Также хранилище Vuex поддерживает модульность, то есть можно создать отдельные модули для разных сегментов приложения `new Vuex({ modules: {...}})`.

И конечно это не отменяет возможность загрузки данных в компоненте, возможность использовать локальное состояние. **Но вы неизбежно столкнетесь с необходимостью уведомлять другие компоненты об изменения состояния**. Централизованное хранилище, хоть и выглядит сложновато, помогает решить множество проблем согласованности и значительно упрощает логику приложения.

Comment: В ссылке что вы приложили (номер 2) предлагается фетчить данные в хуку `Created` либо в `beforeRouteEnter` но это всё же не в контейнере Vuex. В моём случае я не предполагаю данные темы форума хранить в центральном хранилище, я предполагал просто один раз их получить при вызове страницы темы форума. Я не спорю, извините если у меня тон такой, хочу разобраться.

Comment: Как я понимаю центральное хранилище нужно для общей либо сохранённой информации на всём сайте, а функцию вытаскивания данных для темы форума, мне кажется логичным хранить в самом компоненте темы форума.

Comment: Если кажется логичным - нужно делать. Логика и опыт дадут нужный результат. Данные динамичны они изменяются, а Vuex - это состояние(+данные). Vuex дает возможность реагировать множеству компонентов на события. / Дополнил ответ. Выбор конечно за вами.

Comment: Ну да, всё логично, просто получение тем форума никак не отражается на других компонентах, это чисто локальное действие, на состояние приложение оно не влияет. Спасибо за ответ и за ссылки, там написано как делать фетчинг, и я буду делать согласно рекомендации, это лучше чем городить самостоятельно. Теперь по поводу решения самого вопроса, я буду точно использовать префикс `Page` так как мне это удобно, но насчёт `WithGetData` буду думать как обойтись без него, буду думать над красивыми названиями отражающими суть компонента.

Comment: С другой стороны реально можно все действия форума засунуть в модуль Vuex Forum. Подумаю как мне больше подходит.